# Ruby on Rails 3.2.1 Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Just started converting my second app from rails 2.3.11 to 3.2.1 - I've hit a problem however with my routes..

This is my old routes file:

```
map.namespace(:admin) do |admin|
 admin.resources :products, :has_many => [:categories, :product_versions, :extra_documents]
 admin.resources :product_versions, :has_many => [:sub_versions]
 admin.resources :categories, :has_many => [:sub_categories, :sub_emanuals, :sub_tests]
end
```

This is what I now have in my rails3 routes.rb file:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :products
  resources :product_versions
  resources :categories
end
```

This seems to be causing problems in my view where I have this:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Categories", admin_product_categories_url(product) %>
```

as in rails 3 is no longer understands what this is, I use this format A LOT in this application.
I tried to work around this after seeing the output of "rake routes" and I used:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Categories", admin_categories_url(product) %>
```

However, in the html code served up it gave me a URL of "http://localhost:3000/admin/categories.21" - see the .21 not /21

Can anyone else on this one please?

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
  admin_category_url(category)
```

ie. one category

Having said that,

Don't you want:

```
admin_product_category(product, category)
```

In which case you need to nest your routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :products do
    resources :categories
  end
  resources :product_versions
end
```

Comment: Fantastic! I'll use the nested routes as I do need the admin_product_category(product, category) - however when I put these in place I get this error "The action 'show' could not be found for Admin::ProductsController" Any ideas?

Comment: There needs to be at least a show view file in the admin/products directory. It seems like the products controller exists so it's likely to be the view file; the action isn't strictly required and I assume you don't have one.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my index action, I had it doing a redirect_to :action => 'list' swapping this for a render seems to fix the problem